# Route public subnet to client location

Tags: routing, subnet, tunnel

Due to the fact that my ISP introduced CGN/DSLite and I still need public IPv4 addresses, I was thinking about tunneling an unused /29 that I own from my server to my local Linux box.

After doing some research, I can't figure out to make that work, either with OpenVPN or GRE. Maybe I was searching for the wrong terms, but it seems that the problem is pretty hard to solve.

### Details:

Server in Datacenter running Debian Wheezy + OpenVZ Kernel + /28 used locally on the server and an unused /29 netblock.

Client home server running Ubuntu 14.04.

Is there any way to route the entire /29 to the local Ubuntu client server? (Maybe using some tunnel techniques... I thought of setting up an IPFire VM, or some other router OS there to handle the local DHCP and such.)

Comment: You could do that, but since you have IPv6 you may as well start using it.

Comment: IPv6 isn't the Issue (i have a HE Tunnel running for years now) but since most Mobile Providers don't have v6 Support (at least here) i have to find some way to access my Contacts, Calendars etc. from remote. Also most public Hotspots don't support v6 by now so in fact v6 is not the Problem in my case, only the lack of v6 support by now.

Comment: What the challenge with doing it with OpenVPN? That's a pretty basic VPN task.

Comment: The challenge is, i don't get i how to do it. Normal OpenVPN isn't a problem but i want to have the Tunnelendpoint on my Debian Server at Home as a Gateway for the /29 i have and from there distribute the Net to my local Clients, at least 2-3 of them. Maybe my Question was a little unclear at all so again what i want to acchieve: I need a (i guess) a Site to Site VPN/Tunnel from my DC Server to my Home Server and install there IPFire/WhateverFirewallOS and let it act as DHCP+NAT Gateway for my normal Clients and also Distribute the /29 to special Clients on my Net.